# Wordpress HTML AJAX JSON get data and parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

There is a JSON file that is associated with this link provided in the code below. How can I get the data from it and Ajax update data? So far this is what I have. However, the button doesnt even work and i'm not even sure my coding is correct to pull the data correctly. Sorry, i'm new with this coding stuff.

```html
<html>

<head>

<metacontent=”text/html; charset = ISO-8859-1″http-equiv=”content-type”>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script>
function loadJSON(){

var data_file=”https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo;;

var http_request =newXMLHttpRequest();

try{

// Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari

http_request =newXMLHttpRequest();

}catch(e){

// Internet Explorer Browsers{

try{

http_request =newActiveXObject(“Microsoft.XMLHTTP”);

}catch(e){

// Something went wrong

alert(“Your browser broke!”);

returnfalse;

}

}

}

http_request.onreadystatechange =function(){

if(http_request.readyState ==4){

// Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

// jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can

// be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.

document.getElementById(“open”).innerHTML = jsonObj.open;

document.getElementById(“high”).innerHTML = jsonObj.high;

}

}

http_request.open(“GET”, data_file,true);

http_request.send();

}

</script>

<title>tutorialspoint.com JSON</title>

</head>

 

<body>

<h1>Stock details</h1>

<tableclass=”src”>

<tr><th>Open</th><th>High</th></tr>

<tr><td>123.4

</td>

<td>150.87

</td></tr>

</table>
<button type="button" onclick="loadJSON();">Update Details </button>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery slim doesn't support AJAX. Use normal jQuery :)

Also, consider using getJSON

```
$.getJSON('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    //do stuff with your data
});
```

Comment: Thanks I updated my jQuery. And used the getJSON. Still not working though. Do you have an example I can use for this? Also, I know that Wordpress has some sort of extra hooks you have to put on for ajax code. Do you have a source where I can read what needs to be done?